# How to initialize href using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to append my href attribute values by using the below code

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     jQuery("#help_url").click(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(href);
        var txt_api_key = $('#txt_api_key').val();
        var txt_postcode = $('#txt_postcode').val();
        var txt_countrycode = $('#txt_countrycode').val();
        $('a#help_url').attr('href', href+txt_postcode+"/"+txt_countrycode+"?api_key="+txt_api_key);
    });
});
```

This is working perfect. But the issue is after the first click the link will become http://api.fastway.org/v1/psc/pickuprf/2148/1?api_key=5340c900251a6105a19a58a1590472bb and on the next click after I changing the "txt_countrycode" value or if not chnaging any value it becomes http://api.fastway.org/v1/psc/pickuprf/2148/1?api_key=5340c900251a6105a19a58a1590472bb2148/1?api_key=5340c900251a6105a19a58a1590472bb

ie, again adding "href+txt_postcode+"/"+txt_countrycode+"?api_key="+txt_api_key"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy solution is to read the value of the href in dom ready and use it in the click handler, so that the `href` will have a non updated value

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var href = jQuery('#help_url').attr('href');
    jQuery("#help_url").click(function () {
        alert(href);
        var txt_api_key = $('#txt_api_key').val();
        var txt_postcode = $('#txt_postcode').val();
        var txt_countrycode = $('#txt_countrycode').val();
        $('a#help_url').attr('href', href + txt_postcode + "/" + txt_countrycode + "?api_key=" + txt_api_key);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click the button the click event will call .
the click event function have concatenation with existing url.So the existing url is append with country code